# Simple react form validation with yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm trying to learn form validation with yup and react-hook-form and, ideally want to set the validation to also require at least one of the two different-named radio options, but first understand why the `isValid` variable is false.

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup"

const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async data => {
    console.log('form data', data);
    const isValid = await schema.isValid();
    console.log('isValid', isValid);
  }

  return (
    <>
    {console.log('errors', errors)}
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="name" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
      
      <input name="nameTwo" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}

      <label>
        <input
          name="test"
          type="radio"
          ref={register}
          value="test"
        />
    </label>

    <label>
        <input
          name="testTwo"
          type="radio"
          ref={register}
          value="testTwo"
        />
    </label>
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    </>
  );
}

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string(),
  nameTwo: yup.string().required(),
  test: yup.string(),
  testTwo: yup.string()
})

export default App
```

So the schema defines only one field (`nameTwo`) as required, but even when filling in that field it still is false. Why is `isValid` not true? And how is it best to go about making either one of the two radio buttons (`test` or `testTwo`) required?

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-93vahd

Thank you

Comment: On line 9, you called `schema.isValid()` without any arguments. Also, you may find [validation resolvers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/resolvers) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isValid` property is available in the `formState` object returned from the `useForm` hook.

You'll notice that `onSubmit` is not called unless the Yup validation passes. Therefore `isValid` will always be true when checking inside the onSubmit callback.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    formState: { isValid }
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async data => {
    console.log('form data', data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log('isValid', isValid)}
      {console.log('errors', errors)}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input name="name" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />

        <input name="nameTwo" ref={register({ required: true })} />
        {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}

        <label>
          <input name="test" type="radio" ref={register} value="test" />
        </label>

        <label>
          <input name="testTwo" type="radio" ref={register} value="testTwo" />
        </label>

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string(),
  nameTwo: yup.string().required(),
  test: yup.string(),
  testTwo: yup.string()
});

export default App;
```